# Post a Json file to elasticsearch running on Docker, Kitematic on Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, curl, elasticsearch, docker

I have been looking all over the internet without any luck. 
I am trying to post a file `fluidflux.json` ~10Gb to a elasticsearch docker image running on Windows 10, but without succeeding.

Can anyone help me figure out the proper Post command and where to locally put my file?

I am running curl within the Kitematic Powershell that comes with the Windows Docker "suite". I mounted a volume:

[image: Elasticsearch docker image - volume mounted]

I placed my the file in the local folder "data" and run my command but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to split your 10GB file into several ~3mb files and use the bulk API to send the data. Its a lot easier to do that with a python script than with curl, but if you want to use curl anyway:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_bulk?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @fluidflux_part1.json
```

your json file should have lines separated by \n like below, so a little pre-processing needs to be done:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "myindex", "_type" : "mytype", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "name" : "john" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "myindex", "_type" : "mytype", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "name" : "mary" }
```